# add stroke to text (outline) with Coldfusion and Java (classes/methods)

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I've been trying to add stroke to text using Coldfusion code and Java classes / methods. I found some pointers on Leigh's old blog (cfsearching) and have been spending a lot of my free time reading more about Java objects, how to call Java class/method .etc on Ben Nadel's blog. I have a lot to learn on this and I would be happy to do so with your help :)

I put together a test code, here is what I have so far

```
<cfset text = "This is just a text sample">
<cfset img = imageNew("",500,500,"rgb","blue")>
<cfset graphics = ImageGetBufferedImage(img).getGraphics()>
<cfset renderContext = graphics.getFontRenderContext()>

<!---get font details--->
<cfset Font = createObject("java", "java.awt.Font")>
<cfset NewFont = Font.init( "Arial", Font.BOLD, javacast("int", 40))>
<cfset txtLayout = createObject("java", "java.awt.font.TextLayout").init( text,NewFont,renderContext)>
<cfset txtBounds = txtLayout.getBounds()>
<cfset txtWidth = txtBounds.getWidth()>
<cfset txtHeight = txtBounds.getHeight()>
<cfset shapeObj = createObject("java", "java.awt.geom.AffineTransform").init()>
<cfset shape = txtLayout.getOutline(shapeObj)>

<!---set stroke  ---> 
<cfset color = createObject("java", "java.awt.Color")> 
<cfset stroke = createObject("java", "java.awt.BasicStroke").init(10)> 
<cfset strokeWidth = stroke.getLineWidth()>
<cfset graphics.setStroke( stroke )>
<cfset graphics.setColor( color.decode("##ff0600"))>

<!---write on image--->
<cfset attr = { font="Arial", size="40", style="bold" }>
<cfset x = (ImageGetWidth(img) / 2 - txtWidth / 2)>
<cfset y = (ImageGetHeight(img) / 2 + txtHeight / 2)>  
<cfset imageSetDrawingColor(img,"yellow")>
<cfset imageDrawText(img,shape, x, y, attr)>

<cfimage source="#img#" action="writeToBrowser">
```

I am aware that I somehow incorrectly combine CF and Java and that's why I would really appreciate your help on this one :) I also tried dumping almost every variable in order to see what's hiding behind, what methods/classes can be accessed, though I was not able to sort it out :((

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to both fill the text with color *and* outline it, then you really cannot mix the two drawing functions (CF and java). It is difficult to match the positioning exactly, so you frequently end up with a shadow, rather than an outline. For consistent results, I would draw all of the text in java.

First get the graphical representation of the text:

```
graphics = ImageGetBufferedImage(img).getGraphics();
context = graphics.getFontRenderContext();
Font = createObject("java", "java.awt.Font");
textFont = Font.init( "Arial", Font.BOLD, javacast("int", 40));
textLayout = createObject("java", "java.awt.font.TextLayout").init( text, textFont, context);
```

Then calculate the positions to center the text. This part is a little counter-intuitive, but ... basically you use the AffineTransform to set the position *before* drawing it onto the image:

```
transX = (imageWidth/2) - textLayout.getBounds().getWidth()/2;
transY = (imageHeight/2) + textLayout.getDescent();
transform = createObject("java", "java.awt.geom.AffineTransform").init();
transform.setToTranslation( transX, transY );
```

Next, get the text shape, and fill it with whatever background color you want:

```
// fill it with a "yellow" background
shape = textLayout.getOutline(transform);
color = createObject("java", "java.awt.Color"); 
graphics.setColor( color.decode("##ffff00") );
graphics.fill( shape );
```

Finally, draw the text outline:

```
// finally, draw a "red" outline
graphics.setColor( color.decode("##ff0600"));
stroke = createObject("java", "java.awt.BasicStroke").init(1); 
graphics.setStroke( stroke );
graphics.draw( shape );
```

Then display the image as usual:

```
<cfimage source="#img#" action="writeToBrowser">
```

[image]